# What does it mean to "find a command in a path"?

Tags: linux, shell, path, environment-variables

This is an excerpt from the instructions of my homework for my operating systems class. The bolded portion is the part I cannot make sense of, nor can I reach the professor right now and I'd really like to start this tonight. I know what an environment variable is, I suppose...just a variable declared in the shell, right? But what does the bolded line in particular mean?

> Write a C program to implement an interactive shell in which users execute commands.
>
> Call this program myshell (so use gcc -o myshell -Wall etc. to
>   compile).
>
> Create an infinite loop that repeatedly prompts the user to enter a
>   command (see example output and input below).
>
> **Before executing the command entered by the user, the command must be
>   found using the path specified by environment variable THEPATH (do not
>   use PATH!).** By default, the THEPATH variable is not set, so for
>   testing, you'll want to set (and unset) this variable manually (see
>   details below). If THEPATH is found, your program must execute the
>   command in a child process via fork() and one of the exec() system
>   calls.
>
> To obtain and parse THEPATH, consider using the getenv() function and
>   the  strtok() or strsep() functions.

Comment: The last sentence there says "To obtain and parse THEPATH, consider using the getenv() function and the strtok() or strsep() functions."  Are you asking how shell `PATH` variables work in general?  For that, you can look in the `bash` man page under "COMMAND EXECUTION".

Comment: I just don't understand the concept of "getting the command using the path." I literally have no idea what that sentence means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a shell to run a program, it has to know where that program is.  For example, you want to be able to type `ls` at the prompt, but the actual binary for `ls` might be found at `/bin/ls`.  That's where `PATH` (or your case, `THEPATH`) comes in.  When you type `ls`, the shell goes off and looks in each `PATH` directory for a program with a matching name.  When it finds one, it runs it.  Let's use `ls` as an example, and a `PATH` set to:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Assuming `ls` is `/bin/ls`, then the shell first looks for `ls` in `/usr/local/bin`, doesn't find it, then looks in `/usr/bin`, and then finally finds it in `/bin` and executes it.

Actually *doing* this operation is where the hint in your assignment about `getenv`, `strtok`, and `strsep` comes in.

Comment: Great explanation. One other thing though. Keep in mind you're talking to an OS noob. Why is the path in your example (the professor gave a comparable example) full of usr and bin repeated over and over? Am I thinking of this wrong? I'm used to paths narrowing down as they go on, i.e. MaryDawn/Documents/OldEssays/HistoryClass/Jefferson.txt, not just MaryDawn/documents/Marydawn:Documents/Marydawn, if this is making sense.

Comment: It's 3 different paths, separated by colons.  First, `/usr/local/bin`, second, `/usr/bin`, and third, `/bin`.  Those are all pretty standard directories on a unix machine.  Type `echo ${PATH}` in the shell to see what yours is set to.  You can use `which` (like `which ls` for example) to see where some of the utilities you commonly use are located.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `THEPATH` should contains a list of directories, separated by a colon, as in

```
THEPATH=/usr/bin:/bin:some-other-dirs
```

You must parse this into a list of directories. When the user enters a command, you must scan all the directories in order to find an executable whose name matches the command entered by the user.

Writing a shell at this level of sophistication is not a beginner task, and if you don't understand how the system's PATH handling works (you are just emulating what the shell does), you may be in over your head.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but you can play a dirty trick here in the spirit of Master Foo's "gaining merit by not coding". The `execlp()`, `execvp()` and `execvpe()` C-library functions actually search the PATH variable for you. All you have to do is to replace PATH with your THEPATH in the environment. It makes your shell safer as well, because all your child processes will use your original THEPATH as PATH.

```
int i_path = -1;
int i_thepath = -1;
int i = 0;
while (envp[i] != NULL) {
    if (strstr(envp[i], "PATH=") == envp[i])
        i_path = i;
    if (strstr(envp[i], "THEPATH=") == envp[i])
        i_thepath = i;
    i++;
}
if (i_path >= 0 && i_thepath >= 0)
    envp[i_path] = envp[i_thepath] + 3; /* discard 'THE' */
else if (i_thepath >= 0)
    envp[i_thepath] = envp[i_thepath] + 3; /* discard 'THE' */
execvpe(command, argv, envp);
```

If you go for a manual parsing of THEPATH, do not create a list of directories. It's easy in a high level language like Perl, but involves manual dynamic memory allocation in C, because you don't know beforehand how many dir elements are there in THEPATH. And to do the memory allocation you need to iterate through the string first. But you can do the real job during the first iteration, using `strtok()` with `":"` as the separator.

```
char *thepath = envp[i_thepath];
char *dir;
strtok(thepath, "="); /* first discard 'THEPATH=' */
while (dir = strtok(NULL, ":") {
    /* now check if dir+command exists and is execuatble, exec */
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I like this much, but I suppose it would work. I doubt if the person setting the question would accept it, though. Note that the best way to find out if the command is executable is to attempt to `execv()` or `execve()` the combined name `dir/command`. If the `exec*()` operation works, you won't return to the calling code.  If the `exec*()` operation fails (perhaps because the file exists, is accessible, has the execute bit set — but the relevant command interpreter listed in the `#!` shebang is missing), then it returns and you can try the next directory on THEPATH (or the PATH).

Comment: Yes, you're right, actually attempting exec*() is easier that stat-ing the file beforehand.